# Print to Tkinter GUI, not console

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have some scripts written containing a handful of functions to do some webscraping. When running the scripts, the results print to the IDLE shell using simple 'print' commands.

I have a basic tkinter GUI that will run the script when a button is clicked, but the results still get printed to the shell. How could I adjust my code so that when Master.master() is called, all the print statements embedded in that process print to some area on my GUI. The code I have is the following:

```
from tkinter import *
import Master #Importing my scraper function

win = Tk()
win.title('Hashtag Scraper')

SearchButton = Button(win,text = 'Search')

SearchButton.grid(row=2,column = 1)

htag_label = Label(win,text = 'What Hashtag?')
htag_label.grid(row = 1,column = 0)

email_label = Label(win,text = 'FB Email')
email_label.grid(row = 1,column = 1)

password_label = Label(win,text = 'FB Password')
password_label.grid(row = 1,column = 2)

def button():
    htag = hashtag.get()
    user = usr.get()
    password = pwd.get()
    Master.master(htag,refresh = 3,usr = user,pwd = password) #Function call - want this to print on GUI instead of shell

#win.bind('<Return>', SearchButton)

SearchButton.configure(command = button)


hashtag = StringVar()
#hashtag.set('Hashtag')
hashtag_entry = Entry(win,textvariable=hashtag)
hashtag_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

usr = StringVar()
usr.set('test@aol.com')
usr_entry = Entry(win,textvariable=usr)
usr_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

pwd = StringVar()
#pwd.set('FB Password')
pwd_entry = Entry(win,textvariable=pwd)
pwd_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
```

Comment: You can insert the output into a tkinter textbox.

Comment: I apologize for my python ignorance but would that be as simple as changing the final 'print' statement in my main function into return and setting than setting a variable as that result?

Comment: it is pretty simple, just read it here : http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where on your GUI and what kind of widget you want to display the result of your `master` method call, or perhaps in a new popup TextBox window as mentioned in the comments, change it to the kind of widget you wish to use:

```
class Master:
    def __init__(self, htag, refresh, usr, pwd):
        self.htag = htag
        self.refresh = refresh
        self.usr = usr
        self.pwd = pwd

    def master(self):
        return '\n'.join([self.htag, str(self.refresh), self.usr, self.pwd])
```

...

```
def button():
    htag = hashtag.get()
    user = usr.get()
    password = pwd.get()
    m = Master(htag, refresh = 3, usr = user, pwd = password)
    master_response = m.master() #Function call - want this to print on GUI instead of shell

    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Response from master method")
    # response_message = "Search Button pushed response"
    msg = Message(top, text=master_response)
    msg.pack()

    button = Button(top, text="Dismiss", command=top.destroy)
    button.pack()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is definitley close to what I am looking for. I Don't want anything displayed until the "search" button is clicked. Furthermore my "Master" function doesn't actually return anything, it just has several print statements throughout displaying the results. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure does :) I just wanted to provide an idea, and if this is put in the `button()` method, it would display text the text only after the button is pressed, and the text would be the `master()` method text in a return variable. So all the `print` statements in `Master.master()` could be put into one `return` statement at the end of that method (maybe something like `return ' '.join(text1, text2)`), which get returned to the `master_response` variable (commented out here, but you would use it) and put into widget parameters as `text = master_response`.

Comment: I'll update the answer to demonstrate if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: So would I need to go into my actual scripts and change some "print" statements to "return"? I am still a bit confused and it probably does not help that you can't see the scripts I'm talking about lol

Comment: @JoeyB, sorry my explanation was very poor, I've updated the code to show what I mean,

Comment: Argggg I feel like I'm close but I still am not seeing what I want. I think the problem is setting m = Master.master() doesn't return anything. I would show you more of my code in other scripts but it doesn't seem possible to share code like that in the comments. *sigh* I may just have to move on from this...

Comment: Yes, `m = Master.master` won't work yet, because your method doesn't return anything *yet*. So I just added that line to give you an *example* of how to use it, since you didn't include it in your question. But, you can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44571886/edit) your question and include *any* code you want. If you want to include some of the `Master.py` code I could try to update the answer to work for your specific case... But if you do still want to move on from it, feel free to delete your question and/or ask a new one... Whatever you choose, good luck!